Concurent request duplicate record in spring jpa under transaction
Hi i use spring jpa to insert a record,my problem is if id exist on database use this record otherwise generate it and this generation process must be transactional.Before i insert record i check it is exist on database.My problem is when two request come at same time this control is not working.i put unique constraint to database but that time one of the request failed.How can i make record exist case under transaction control for concurent request?
@transactional
Public void save()  { checkexist ? Useit: create

generally, jpa use optimistic locking.
then you said 'if id exist on database use this record otherwise generate it and this generation process' not guarantee atomic operation per transaction.
the comparison between entities in the persistence context is made only at the point of commit()
I think the simple solution is to strictly change the Isolation level.
otherwise, if ids size is small and the application does not run in multiple processes, how about just making and using a counter object in thread-safe.

id is guid and assign from payload our concern is we want to create this record only one time and create at one than use this id and not to generate second ,which isolation level are you suggested?

when i read it again, the situation is you trying to save entities with same key but different states by checking existence origin key at first. (if same states, error is just normal). i suggest write @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) on top of your repository function. it will prevent reading same record by other transactions. refer
